What did Rohan and Gondor think Sauron was?
From the point of view of humans Sauron:

Returns after being defeated generations ago
Commands orcs, ringwraiths, trolls and other evil beings
Uses magic (creation of the rings, controlling weather)

What kind of being did they think the Enemy was? Did they know he was a Maia?
The Mouth of Sauron is described as a Black Númenórean man who has been taught magic so they could also take Sauron to be a Man. Saruman was an evil wizard so they could think Sauron was one too. Elves are immortal and seem magical to Men so that is also not outlandish.

Saruman wasn't evil seemingly evil before the events in LotR. It's only once he meddled with the Palantir that he started to be influenced IIRC, and it wasn't until Council of Elrond in Rivendell that Gandalf revealed the change in Saruman to the allies (Gandalf was imprisoned by Saruman while Frodo is escaping from the Shire). Saruman was "good" at the time of the expulsion of the Necromancer (Sauron) from Dol Guldur immediately prior to the events in the Hobbit.

He was absolutely evil by the end and that matters most.

@bob1 He was turning to evil well before then, as he hid from the Council that he thought the Ring was still hidden somewhere, and counseled against driving out The Necromancer, hoping the Ring would reveal itself if Sauron were left alone for a bit. Only when he saw The Necromancer searching (fruitlessly, as the Ring had been moved by Smeagol) did he agree to try to remove The Necromancer.

@MichaelFoster In the context of the question - he wasn't apparently evil to those outside of his inner circle. From the point of view of humans in LotR, he would just have seemed to be a normal wizard, not an evil one. Gandalf suspected that he was evil but had no real proof until it was revealed in the Fellowship with the "breaking the white" robe.

For most of the people of Middle Earth, what Sauron was categorically was not likely something they ever thought about. Even for the people to whom it mattered, it likely only mattered in as much as it directed how to deal with him. Categorical specificity like you seem to expect here would have only been of interest to academics or theologians (and theologians may not have cared either depending on the circumstances).

Who is "they"? Aragorn and Denethor would have known what Sauron was. The grunts in the Gondorian army would have been too busy trying to kill enemies while not getting killed to worry about who the Enemy was. Faramir and Boromir probably knew it in theory, but likely were more concerned with helping their men to survive.

@bob1 that happens during The Hobbit, not before.

@OrangeDog No they don't. Gandalf realizes Saruman isn;t being entirely forthcoming, so goes to Gondor to look at their records from Isildur. He then realizes Bilbo's ring is a "great ring", and Bilbo doesn't reveal the ring until after the events in Hobbit. Gandalf and Aragorn leave it for a bit before searching for Gollum. They find Gollum, question him and Gandalf goes to Frodo and confirms the ring, right at the start of LotR. Gandalf is captured by Saruman before confirming the ring though - text says "at the end of June I was on the borders of the Shire", meets Radogast there, who...

@bob1 "the expulsion of the Necromancer (Sauron) from Dol Guldur immediately prior to the events in the Hobbit" is what I was referring to

@OrangeDog ...tells him Saruman is looking for him, so G goes to Orthanc and is captured by S. Reveals this at the Council of Elrond.  Time frame is the last June according to the quote above. Frodo leaves Shire in September after waiting for  and arrives in Rivendell in a month or two later in early winter after waiting for Gandalf, who doesn't come, presumably because he was captured.

@OrangeDog Yes, happens during Hobbit I think - when Gandalf goes off before Mirkwood.

While there is certainly a classification of beings in Tolkien's universe, and many learned people in Gondor would have known who and what Sauron was, I think it's fair to say that Tolkien didn't categorize his characters in such a strict fashion, and by extension neither did his characters themselves. They wouldn't have gone around asking exactly where everyone fits in the "tree of life" of Arda.
Let me expand: At the beginning of the Silmarillion, it seems like you just have the Ainur, Men and Elves - the original plan, so to speak. Immediately we are introduced to the Dwarves, and to the Ents and Eagles, who are sort of "spirits" - fully conscious and intelligent, but not children of Ilúvatar. Then comes Ungoliant, who very clearly does not fit in this classification, and the dragons, who are kind of weird, not to mention the orcs whose origin Tolkien never managed to resolve. In The Lord of the Rings it gets more complicated: there are hobbits, there are wizards, there's Tom Bombadil and Goldberry, there's the "nameless things" under Moria like the Watcher, the Huorns, the spiders, the Barrow Downs spirits, and so on. I think the wizards are particularly interesting because even though they are obviously immortal (or very long lived), no one seems to think they are Elves. They're just accepted as wizards, whatever they are.
And this is my point: this world is full of all kinds of creatures, with varying degrees of longevity and consciousness. Some of them are easily classifiable, some of them not so much. I think the people of Middle-Earth would have accepted Sauron as simply Sauron: an evil overlord with evil powers. If you had been born there, I don't think you would have expected to be able to classify everyone you hear about.

And perhaps Tolkien multiplied the character types to keep in his back pocket in the case his complicating plot development required some among them more or less.

“I think the people of Middle-Earth would have accepted Sauron as simply Sauron” — This is certainly the picture LotR presents to an ordinary first-time reader (not knowing the Silmarillion or other deeper lore); so under the fiction that LotR is based on the Red Book, this is the view as presented by relatively learned and worldly inhabitants of the Shire

"Gandalf" means "wand-elf".  So, back before there was a word for "wizard", it was assumed he was an elf by someone.

@DougWarren That's a good point. But then again, Sam says in front of Gandalf that he's excited to go see the Elves - so he doesn't think Gandalf is an elf. It's certainly possible that some people did.

@DougWarren and in English 'Alfred' means 'elf-counsel' but I wouldn't assume anyone called Alf' is an elf.

@PeteKirkham I wouldn't either, normally.  But I might if he was in a book about elves and his name was "Counsel-Elf".

Orcs are accounted by Tolkien. They originated in Elves that had been corrupted by Melkor.

@DougWarren: Wiki says "Gandalf" was originally coined by the Men of Arnor (Aragorn's ancestors in the north), and spread from there, and does confirm that it's supposed to mean "Wand-Elf". That said, it also says most people assumed he was human who happened to be able to do magic (which tracks with my memory of how most humans and hobbits seem to treat him), rather than a higher being. The "Elf" part could simply refer to his knowledge and longevity, rather than thinking he was truly an elf (he doesn't look like one at all AFAICT).

@toolforger It’s a lot more complicated than that.  That is what Christopher Tolkien put in the Silmarillion, but his father wrestled the origins of orcs his entire life, and never settled on one.  Even in the Silmarillion that is not stated as a fact, but something the elves very strongly believe.

@ShadowRanger indeed, there are no known elves (certainly not in Middle Earth) that look like an old man, and only one with a beard.

In addition to creatures of all shapes and sizes there are also (not well-documented) artifacts of the ancient that may further transform the beings beyond recognition.

@Doug Warren In our world, "Gandalf" means "wand-elf" and that is where Tolkien drew the name. It does not follow that that is the name's origin in the world of LotR. Note also that Gandalf went my many names, seemingly a different one for each group he interacted with.

I think the origin of Gandalf's name as "wand-elf" comes from either the appendices to The Lord of the Rings or from The Silmarillion.  If I remember correctly, I think that was what a tribe of "Westron" men had called him when they first met him, perhaps around the beginning of the Third Age.  If so, that derivation comes from inside the fictional universe.

“…and so he was called among Men of the North Gandalf, “The Elf of the Wand.”  For they deemed him (though in error, as has been said) to be of Elven-kind…”. Unfinished Tales, the Istari

Just as Anglo-Saxon is the real-world stand-in for the language of the Rohirrim, Old Norse is the stand-in for the (admittedly hardly attested) language of their ancestors. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalf_(mythology).

I don't think there's any reason to believe they think he's anything other than what he is.
As Gandalf tells the Council of Elrond, he had discovered that the Necromancer at Dol Guldur was Sauron many years before. And then during the events of The Hobbit, the White Council drive him out of Dol Guldur:

But we were too late, as Elrond foresaw. Sauron had also watched us, and had long prepared against our stroke [...] Then he gave way before us, but only feigned to flee, and soon after came to the Dark Tower and openly declared himself.

So his identity was far from a secret by the time of LoTR, at least to the Wise (which at that point included Saruman). And both Gondor and Rohan were still friendly with Gandalf at that point; plus, Aragorn served in both countries under the guise of Thorongil.
So if there was no secret about his identity, and people in a position to know that identity were present, there's no reason to think it would not have been widely known.
Certainly by the time of the War of the Ring the leaders of both countries, and even some of the common people in Gondor, do seem to know who they're fighting.

Also, while Rohan’s knowledge of such things is uncertain, the people of Gondor were very aware of the Ainur and what they were. And they had a history with Sauron, via Numenor, that went back to the War of the Elves and Sauron and including his ‘captivity’ in Numenor, there is no reason to doubt they knew. Sauron was not hiding it, like the wizards did (except as the Necromancer).

Are there any in-text references where humans or elves in the Third Age refer to him as a Maia or a non-human being?

@dubious I recall that Aragorn, when he related the story of Beren and Tinuviel to the hobbits, said that Sauron was only a servant of the Great Enemy of the First Age. This certainly implies that he is not human, since he has lived for three ages. However, most of the characters do not even name Sauron, much less discuss him or his origins. Faramir says, explicitly, "we do not name" him. They might know about him, but they do not say.

@dubious The term Maia/Maiar never appears in Lord of the Rings, same with Ainur, though the Valar are occasionally referred to.

@dubious The Silmarillion is supposed to be things the Elves wrote down, having heard things from the Valar and such. Some, such as Galadriel, were around from the First through the Third Age (Elrond was, too, but he probably didn't hear much from the Valar directly).

I was in error. It is Beregond who refers to Sauron as "he whom we do not name" or something like that. Perhaps Faramir also said something of the sort.

"He whom we do not name" is something you don't say about a human, so they definitely know he is not a human.

@suchiuomizu: One caveat to the "Sauron was not hiding it" - as I understand, he often hid his identity, often by using a different name and appearance.
But yeah - he didn't try to make people think that the name "Sauron" meant anything to other people but what he was.

There is a saying "Speak of the Devil and he appears". Many cultures avoid mentioning evil or dangerous being for fear of summoning them.

Ioreth, who is one of the women in the Houses of Healing, said (apropos of Hobbits):

...They are small, but they are valiant. Why, cousin, one of them went with his esquire into the Black Country, and fought with the Dark Lord all by himself, and set fire to his Tower, if you can believe it--Book VI, Chapter 5, the Steward and the King.

If we can take Ioreth as a representative of the ordinary citizens of Gondor, she doesn't appear to consider the idea of Frodo duelling Sauron to be absurd; it may be a David & Goliath battle, but, in her opinion, not out of the question for a brave little guy. Notice that she doesn't use the Sauron's name: Faramir said that they don't name him.

I love this quote. It shows that how in-universe, the average person knows such a sketchy and vague idea of even recent historical (and historic) events. It's a bit like Frodo in the Silmarillion, "alone with his servant" destroying the Ring. But what I think is important is that "Dark Lord" here is basically a non-description. It's just a "the leader of the bad guys" type of description.

Actually Ioreth's description does not mean a lot about Sauron's status. Remember that in Tolkien's world, "supernatural" does not mean "invincible"; in fact Sauron was slain by two humans and an elf, despite Sauron having his One Ring. Power levels do not predetermine the outcome, and if three mortals could topple a half-god, Ioreth would be in her full right to believe that a mere hobbit could replicate that feat, given enough luck/smarts/power.
